# Removing dependency on IIS Windows Authentication from a Visual Studio ASP.NET project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis, windows-vista

I have Visual Studio 2008 installed on Windows Vista Home Edition. I need to build and run an ASP.NET project that uses IIS Windows Authentication, which is not available on Vista Home.  Now when I try to open the project in VS I get an error:

> The Web Application project ... is configured to use IIS [...] you must install the following IIS components: Windows Authentication

Can I remove the dependency on the Windows Authentication component from the project somehow, so that I can at least open it in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

In web.config you'll see the line

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

Replace it with

```
<authentication mode="None"/>
```

Notepad should do the job. Of course depending on the actual code that checks identity in the application everything else may fall apart.

Comment: I found the line, but it says: `<authentication mode="Forms"> <forms>[...]</forms></authentication>`. I tried removing the section altogether, but Visual Studio still complains with the same error. I'm starting to suspect that the requirement for 'Windows Authentication' is hardcoded, invoked automatically when a project requires IIS. Any other ideas?

Comment: If it's forms auth then yes, that's weird. I'm afraid I don't have any idea!